# Session and view scoped beans behave as request scoped

Tags: session, jsf, managed-bean

My session scoped and view scoped managed beans behave as request scoped beans. I'm using Mojarra 2.2.8-11 (changed it from 2.2.0).

In view and session scoped beans, the constructor is be called at each request. And, in below bean I'm setting user name as session attribute:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Login {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String login(){
        if(username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")){
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            session.setAttribute("username", username);
            return "home";
        }

        return "error";
}
```

When accessing it later, it is suddenly `null`.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you using Spring or CDI for dependency injection?

Comment: I used dependency injection but also did not work - instance variable remain null - NPE thrown when used

Comment: Where is your username being set in the session? If it is set knowhere,  trying to retrieve it from the session will return null.

Comment: Set in the bean I meant

Comment: if I understand you well, username and password will be set using EL from the login page

Comment: In other words, the HTTP session isn't being maintained and recreated on every request? Have you confirmed this by inspecting the webbrowser's HTTP traffic monitor?

Comment: Try to find, might be there is entry in faces-config of this bean in request scope. This also might be a reason for this issue.

Comment: :D Solved it. I think it was a jar conflicts (they were not compatible). removing all jars and adding new compatible ones solved the issue. thanks all